# Gsp / HTML page not supporting wcm tags

Tags: wcm

I am a newbie to WCM, I am using weceem blog. I want to paginate the blogs, when I try to do it with the offset and max limits,  is not working in the HTML pages in wcm. But, I am able to use some tags like .

Please Help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure weceem is gsp server side based so static resources (html) are not going to work. You need to include your tags in gsp pages

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs I am right

Here, three different Grails taglibs are being used to create the form:
g:hasErrors is a Grails tag used to detect any errors on the submittedContent data and alerts the user if so
wcm:submitContentForm creates a form that will submit content of a specific type, as set in the "type" attribute.

So you need to use gsp and probably return a partial. I would look at angular and ngbindhtml